# How can I use .NET dll in python?

Tags: python-3.x, python.net

I am having a weird error trying to use .NET dll in a python program.

> C:\temp>"c:\apps\WPy64-37120\pypy3.7-v7.3.7-win64\python.exe" example.py

> Failed to initialize pythonnet: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Delegates' threw an exception. ---> Python.Runtime.BadPythonDllException: Runtime.PythonDLL was not set or does not point to a supported Python runtime DLL. See https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet#embedding-python-in-net ---> System.MissingMethodException: Failed to load symbol Py_IncRef. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified procedure could not be found

> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at Python.Runtime.Platform.WindowsLoader.GetFunction(IntPtr hModule, String procedureName)
> at Python.Runtime.Runtime.Delegates.GetFunctionByName(String functionName, IntPtr libraryHandle)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at Python.Runtime.Runtime.Delegates.GetFunctionByName(String functionName, IntPtr libraryHandle)
> at Python.Runtime.Runtime.Delegates..cctor()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at Python.Runtime.Runtime.Delegates.get_PyGILState_Ensure()
> at Python.Runtime.Runtime.PyGILState_Ensure()
> at Python.Runtime.Loader.Initialize(IntPtr data, Int32 size)
> at Python.Runtime.Runtime.Delegates.get_PyGILState_Ensure()
> at Python.Runtime.Runtime.PyGILState_Ensure()
> at Python.Runtime.Loader.Initialize(IntPtr data, Int32 size)Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "example.py", line 2, in 
> from SimpleAxisFile import SimpleAxisFile
> File "c:\apps\WPy64-37120\pypy3.7-v7.3.7-win64\site-packages\SimpleAxisFile_*init*_.py", line 16, in 
> import clr
> File "c:\apps\WPy64-37120\pypy3.7-v7.3.7-win64\site-packages\clr.py", line 6, in 
> load()
> File "c:\apps\WPy64-37120\pypy3.7-v7.3.7-win64\site-packages\pythonnet_*init*_.py", line 44, in load
> raise RuntimeError("Failed to initialize Python.Runtime.dll")
> RuntimeError: Failed to initialize Python.Runtime.dll

The same code used to work with WinPython 3.7 before.

I do have PYTHONNET_PYDLL environment variable set to "C:\apps\WPy64-37120\pypy3.7-v7.3.7-win64\site-packages\pythonnet\runtime\Python.Runtime.dll"

Any ideas why it is not working?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. We (Python.NET) do no support PyPy. I believe it does not provide the same C API as CPython, so it is expected not to work.
2. `PYTHONNET_PYDLL` must point to the DLL that comes with Python, not to `Python.Runtime.dll`. On Windows for CPython 3.9 (for example) it would be called `python39.dll` and should be at the root of the Python installation directory.
3. If you installed `pythonnet` from PyPi and your entry point is Python and not .NET, you should not need to set `PYTHONNET_PYDLL`. The only reason you see it in the error message is because you are trying to use PyPy.